# Instagram API 'Error 500 _makeCall() - cURL error: name lookup timed out'

Tags: instagram

As of the last few hours the Instagram API is returning the following error when I make a request from my server:

> Error 500
>
> Error: _makeCall() - cURL error: name lookup timed out

Anyone else experiencing this issue? Is my server IP banned?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT in instagram's PHP class file:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
```

Changed it from 5 to 30 and now it works albeit a bit slow.